# How do I display list of multi-column clickable items?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to display a list of messages. I want to have multiple fields in each row (Sent by, Message, date), and to be clickable (which then shows the thread the message is part of).

This is what I have so far. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Worr3.jpg

I'm having problems aligning the data in the rows. For now, I have them as three ListItemText components under one ListItem for each row. I tried using tables but I can't get the OnClick function working on it.

What's the best way to get an aligned clickable multi-column list? Similar to gmail's web interface.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the solution you are looking for? I used bootstrap hover table. On clicking the table row, I get the contents of the first cell. May be you should try getting the message ID or something related from the selected table row.

```js
$("#display-table tr").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected'); 
   var value=$(this).find('td:first').html();
   alert(value);    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table id="display-table" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>Sent By</th>
        <th>Message</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>ABC User</td>
            <td>how-do-i-display-list-of-multi-column-clickable-items</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ADC User</td>
            <td>how-do-i-display-list-of-multi-column-clickable-items</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ADE User</td>
            <td>how-do-i-display-list-of-multi-column-clickable-items</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```